# Using FCNN for multi-class semantic segmentation trained on single class labeled image data

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, dataset, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I am working on project where main task is `semantic segmentation` of land cover and another objects in Sentinel 2 multi-spectral images. Currently I posses dataset of 50 000 `single-labeled` images trimmed from Sentinel 2 tiles using OpenStreetMap polygons i.e. every image contains one class e.g. water-body. There is 7 classes in those dataset. Meant for image classification task using convolutional neural networks.

**Is it possible to use those single-labeled images for training `fully convolutional neural network` and then use it for semantic segmentation of (larger) images `containing more classes` e.g. 7 ?**

**Or need I to create new dataset of images, each containing those 7 classes ?**

Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated !

Comment: what you need to do is to create one mask with all (7) labels, and train your network for multi-class segmentation, see this [tutorial](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models/blob/master/examples/multiclass%20segmentation%20(camvid).ipynb) for multi class segmentation.